# Variation on KL-divergence

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following experiment:
I want to *draw* one element $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ with respect to some distribution $\{x\}_{i}$. However, I can only sample these element with respect to the distribution $\{y\}_i$. I want to know how many times I have to sample (in expectation) from the distribution $\{y\}_i$ until I "dominate" one draw of the distribution $\{x\}_i$. With this I mean, how many times do I need to draw according to $\{y\}_i$, such that the probability that I drew element $i$ at least once is at least $x_i$.

Since the probability of drawing element $i$ is $y_i$, I need $\log(1-x_i)-\log(1-y_i)$ draws such that the probability of ending up with one element $i$ is at least $x_i$. This is since $1-(1-y_i)^{\log(1-x_i)-\log(1-y_i)} \geq x_i$. Since we are supposed to draw element $i$ with probability $x_i$, the expected number of draws equals

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \cdot \log(\tfrac{1-x_i}{1-y_i})$$

This is frustratingly close to the KL-divergence, $\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \cdot \log(\tfrac{x_i}{y_i})$. Is there any reinterpretation of the KL-divergence in my setting?